# Connect to a mariadb running on host from docker

Tags: docker, mysql, php, mariadb, nextcloud

I am trying to install nextcloud on a pi. So i installed the docker container, and i can access the first visit page. So i want to use mariadb as database backend.

Then i typed:

host: 192.168.178.62:3306 (host ip + default port)
database name: nextcloud
database password: myspass
database user: nextcloud.

So this gives an error:

```
 Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

What can i do? As i said, the whole thing is running on a pi 3, so i have to keep performance in my mind and not having another container for the database and such things.

Comment: The database is running locally, right? Try using `localhost` instead of the IP. Also, did you create the database user?

Comment: where is running your mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `localhost` you're expecting the database to run in the same docker container as your `nextcloud`. So localhost can't be right in this case. Try to use the IP of your `docker0` interface of your host (IP address).